# Class is taking more computation time if the same input is given over and over

Tags: algorithm, time

I am working on an algorithm and it seems to be working fine, apart from one thing.

Let me first show you the code and then I will explain what the code does and what the problem is.

```
public Triple<List<ROUTE>, Integer, List<Customer>> LocalSearch()
{
    int noImprLS = 0;
    boolean initialization = false;
    List<ROUTE> bestRoutes = startRoutes;
    int bestProfit = profit;
    List<Customer> bestU = u;

    List<ROUTE> tempBestRoutes = startRoutes;
    int tempBestProfit = profit;
    List<Customer> tempBestU = u;
    int tempBestDistance = totalDistance(tempBestRoutes);

    ELIMINATOR e = new ELIMINATOR(bestU, bestRoutes, bestProfit, initialization, name, rnd);

    while (noImprLS <= noImprUB)
    {
        System.out.print(noImprLS);
        boolean improvement = false;
        long starttime = System.nanoTime();
        double timeE = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            long starttimeE = System.nanoTime();
            e = new ELIMINATOR(bestU, bestRoutes, bestProfit, initialization, name, rnd);
            timeE =  timeE + (System.nanoTime()-starttimeE)/1000000000.0;

            POSTPROCEDURE pp = new POSTPROCEDURE(e.getRoutes(), profitRoutes(e.getRoutes()), e.getU(), name);

            for (int p = 0; p < pp.getBestSolution().size(); p++)
            {
                ROUTE r = pp.getBestSolution().get(p);
                addToPOOL(r);       
            }

            int tempprofit = pp.getTP();
            int tempdistance = pp.getTD();

            if (tempprofit > tempBestProfit)  
            {
                tempBestRoutes = pp.getBestSolution();
                tempBestProfit = tempprofit;
                tempBestU = pp.getU();
                tempBestDistance = tempdistance;
            }
            else if (tempprofit == tempBestProfit)
            {

                if (tempdistance < tempBestDistance)
                {
                    tempBestRoutes = pp.getBestSolution();
                    tempBestProfit = tempprofit;
                    tempBestU = pp.getU();
                    tempBestDistance = tempdistance;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tempBestProfit > bestProfit)
        {
            // Move to better neighbor
            bestRoutes = tempBestRoutes;
            bestProfit = tempBestProfit;
            bestU = tempBestU;
            noImprLS = 0;
            improvement = true;
            System.out.print(" total profit: " + bestProfit);
        }
        else if (tempBestProfit == bestProfit)
        {
            if (totalDistance(tempBestRoutes) < totalDistance(bestRoutes))
            {
                // Move to better neighbor
                bestRoutes = tempBestRoutes;
                bestProfit = tempBestProfit;
                bestU = tempBestU;
                noImprLS = 0;
                improvement = true;
                System.out.print(" total profit: " + bestProfit + " total distance: " + totalDistance(bestRoutes));
            }
        }

        if (improvement == false)
        {
            noImprLS++;
        }

        long endtime = System.nanoTime();
        double duration = (endtime - starttime)/1000000000.0;
        System.out.print(" duration: " + duration  + " timeE: " + timeE + "\n");
    }
```

**Explanation**
I know that the code is quite lengthy, but it is all quite important. In this code, I am writing an algorithm for the Team Orienteering Problem with Time Windows (extensive case of the Vehicle Routing Problems). My aim is to find a good set of routes with maximum profit. In the example below, bestRoutes and tempBestRoutes consist of 4 different routes, profit (bestProfit/tempBestProfit) is equal to the total profit of these routes respectively, and (temp)bestU is a list of customers that are not included in my route yet.

The problem now is with ELIMINATOR. This method removes and adds some customers. The output of this class is used for PostProcedure that also changes some facts in the routes.

I hope it is kind of clear now what my code is doing. I am considering N neighbourhoods and I will choose the best one. If the best one is not better than my starting solution, I increase noImprLS with one. I keep on considering new nieghbours until my upperbound on the number of consecutive iterations without improvement is met.

**Problem**
The problem now is that if I have not found a better solution, and hence I keep on inserting the same routes and profit in ELIMINATOR, my computation time increases.

A few examples where duration indicates how long an iteration within the while loop takes, and timeE indicates what the total time of ELIMINATOR in the for loop is. It is clear that ELIMINATOR causees the duration to increase.

0 total profit: 800 duration: 0.486570471 timeE: 0.16644330999999998

0 total profit: 900 duration: 0.431213528 timeE: 0.11342619799999998

0 total profit: 950 duration: 0.444671005 timeE: 0.12090608200000001

0 total profit: 960 duration: 0.519406695 timeE: 0.16836757300000005

0 duration: 0.460473438 timeE: 0.137813155

1 duration: 0.572109775 timeE: 0.30774360900000003

2 duration: 0.698965292 timeE: 0.471859029

3 duration: 0.918376211 timeE: 0.686916669

4 duration: 1.165481175 timeE: 0.92621492

5 duration: 1.326080436 timeE: 1.0874366910000002

6 duration: 2.006102605 timeE: 1.674879135

7 duration: 2.787172112 timeE: 2.4276636639999993

8 duration: 2.042213493 timeE: 1.7967797849999998

9 duration: 2.652985618 timeE: 2.3503671230000003

10 duration: 2.422183993 timeE: 2.1859969810000006

The ELIMINATOR CODE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ELIMINATOR extends BASIS
{
private List<Customer> u;
private List<ROUTE> routes;
private int totalprofit;
private Random prob;

public ELIMINATOR(List<Customer> u, List<ROUTE> routes, int profit, boolean initialization, String name, Random rnd)
{
    super(name);
    this.u = u;
    this.routes = routes;
    this.totalprofit = profit;
    this.prob = rnd;
    if (initialization == true)
    {
        addCustomers();
        for (ROUTE route : routes)
        {
            checkCorrectNess(route, "after adding procedure in eliminator");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        removeCustomers();
        for (ROUTE route : routes)
        {
            checkCorrectNess(route, "after removing procedure in eliminator");
        }
        addCustomers();
        for (ROUTE route : routes)
        {
            checkCorrectNess(route, "after removing and adding procedure in eliminator");
        }

    }
}

public void removeCustomers()
{
    double Ph = 0.1;
    double Pl = 0.3;
    double total_profit = totalprofit;
    int num_customers = 0;

    // Calculate the total profit and total number of customers in the routes
    for(ROUTE route : routes)
    {
        num_customers = num_customers + (route.getLocations().size()-2);
    }

    // Calculate average profit
    double average_profit = total_profit/num_customers;

    // For each customer on each route, determine whether he/she will be removed
    for(ROUTE r : routes)
    {
        List<RouteNode> route = r.getLocations();
        int routesize = route.size();
        int j = 1;
        while (j < routesize-1)
        {
            boolean removed = false;
            RouteNode node = route.get(j);
            if (node.customer.getProfit() >= average_profit)
            {
                if (prob.nextDouble() < Ph)
                {
                    removed = true;
                    RouteNode node_toberemoved = node;
                    int index_node = route.indexOf(node);
                    route.remove(index_node);
                    u.add(node.customer);
                    route = removal(route, node_toberemoved, index_node);
                    r.setLocations(route);
                    r.setDistance(distanceOneRoute(route));
                    r.setProfit(profitOneRoute(route));
                    checkCorrectNess(r, "remove customers eliminator");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (prob.nextDouble() < Pl)
                {
                    removed = true;
                    RouteNode node_toberemoved = node;
                    int index_node = route.indexOf(node);
                    route.remove(index_node);
                    u.add(node.customer);
                    route = removal(route, node_toberemoved, index_node);
                    r.setLocations(route);
                    r.setDistance(distanceOneRoute(route));
                    r.setProfit(profitOneRoute(route));
                    checkCorrectNess(r, "remove customers eliminator");
                }
            }

            if (removed == false)
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                routesize = route.size();
                total_profit = total_profit-node.customer.getProfit();
                average_profit = total_profit/num_customers;
            }
        }
    }
    totalprofit = profitRoutes(routes);
}


public void addCustomers()
{
    List<Customer> u_copy = new ArrayList<Customer>(u);
    List<Customer> u_temp = new ArrayList<Customer>(u);
    for (Customer c : u_temp) 
    {   
        boolean added = false;
        for (ROUTE r : routes)
        {
            checkCorrectNess(r, "add customers eliminator");
            if (added == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            Customer customer = c;
            u_copy.remove(c);

            List<RouteNode> route = r.getLocations();
            for (int i = 0; i < route.size()-1; i++)
            {
                RouteNode possibleNode = new RouteNode();
                possibleNode.customer = customer;

                List<Integer> distances = calculateDistances(route.get(i), possibleNode, route.get(i+1));

                // Calculate shift for customer under consideration
                int arrivalTime = route.get(i).timeStartService+ route.get(i).customer.getService() + distances.get(0); 
                int wait = Math.max(0, customer.getOpeningTW()-arrivalTime);
                int serviceDuration = customer.getService();
                int shift = distances.get(0) + wait + serviceDuration + distances.get(2) - distances.get(1);

                // Determine Start Service
                int startServiceTime = Math.max(customer.getOpeningTW(), arrivalTime); 

                // Obtain waiting time of next customer
                int waiting_next = route.get(i+1).wait;

                // Obtain MaxShift of next customer
                int maxShift = route.get(i+1).maxShift;

                if (shift <= (waiting_next + maxShift) & startServiceTime <= customer.getClosingTW() )
                {
                    // Customer can be inserted
                    added = true;
                    RouteNode newNode = new RouteNode();
                    newNode.customer = customer;
                    newNode.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
                    newNode.timeStartService = startServiceTime;
                    newNode.shift = shift;
                    newNode.wait = wait;

                    int pos_insertion = i + 1;
                    route = ADD(route, newNode, pos_insertion);
                    r.setLocations(route);
                    r.setDistance(distanceOneRoute(route));
                    r.setProfit(profitOneRoute(route));
                    checkCorrectNess(r, "add customers eliminator");
                    // exit the last for loop
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        if (added == false)
        {
            u_copy.add(c);
        }
    }
    u = u_copy;
    totalprofit = profitRoutes(routes);
}

/**
 * Returns list of unvisited customers
 * @return
 */
public List<Customer> getU()
{
    return u;
}

/**
 * Returns list of routes
 * @return
 */
public List<ROUTE> getRoutes()
{
    return routes;
}
```

}

Comment: Since you don't detail the algorithm ELMINATOR uses or show us the code for it, I'm not sure what you want us to do other than suggest that you try optimizing it if you can.

Comment: Also, we can't see what code like `getBestSolution` does. It might just return a reference and be nearly free, or it might do tons of computations. Without knowing, how can we understand what the code is doing?

Comment: If could show you the code of eliminator, but it is quite a lengthy one. My point is just that, if you gave the same input to a class, it should do its calculations within the same time right?

Comment: You cannot expect that in general. An object (instance of a class) has state - the function might be modifying this state, changing the computation/runtime/result for every call.

Comment: @StudentNL It depends what the calculations are and what they depend on. If they're the same calculations, why are you doing them over and over? And if they're not the same, on what is your assumption that they should take the same amount of time based? (There are many ways small changes in inputs can cause huge changes in algorithmic run time.)

Comment: I am doing neighbourhood search. The idea behind the calculations is the same. As you can see, I just inserted my code for the ELIMINATOR. This again contains many other methods, but inserting it all would mean over 5000 lines of code. The only difference in the calculations is caused by a random generator that determines whether a customer gets removed from the route or not. Apart from that, all calculations are the same.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios true, but it seems to be almost linearly increasing in computation time. I did not add all my output, but it starts with less than 1 second, and the last ELIMINATOR takes 16 seconds (60th computation), which is quite a substantial difference.

Comment: @StudentNL I would just add more logging to help narrow it down. Log how much time each part of ELIMINATOR takes, how many loops it has to do, how many calls to `route.remove` and so on. Try to figure out where the difference lies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that is a good advice! I will try that out !

Comment: how do you initialise `startRoutes` before calling `LocalSearch` then?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have found my error, but I do not understand how it happens. In ELIMINATOR, the size of the list of unvisited customers changes (in the first iteration) from 11 to 25, and the number of customers covered in the routes from 39 to 25 (still 50, so fine). When returning to the original method (localSearch) the value of bestU changes immediately, but I do not understand why, since I have no statement for that. Do you understand what I am asking?

Comment: My bet is that you think you have two structures, but actually have two references to the same structure. Since they reference the same structure, when you make changes through one reference, what you see through the other reference also changes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it turned out to be a referencing issue indeed. Thanks a lot!